# Half-size keg force carbonation

Tags: corny-keg, force-carbonation

Today I have 1 half sized corny keg (11,4L - ~3gal) and want to force carbonate it.

Normally when force carbonating normal sized cornys of 5 gal (19L) I use ~30 psi for about 10 minutes.

Don't know if I have to adapt the time of carbing or it tooks the same time to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the surface area exposed (and whether you are shaking the keg).

For the short corny's I've seen, the diameter is the same as a 20L, so the you have the same surface area for half as much beer when the keg is standing. So half the time should work if you're not shaking it.

To carbonate in 10 minutes I suspect you're holding the keg sideways and shaking it. In that case the surface area to beer ratio is probably similar for both kegs, so expect the same time.

A trick I use is to dial down the regulator to the target pressure, give a shake and listen for CO2 going through the regulator. When I can't hear it I know to stop.

Comment: Before I see your answer I take this way of set the target pressure and shake it until i can't hear bubbles or the regulator. I was afraid of super over carbing. It worked very well, I think its so much better than 10 minutes at 30 psi. Was the first time I don't need to take time adjusting the over pressure inside the keg to pouring ok. So I came here and you was saying the same thing! I think that I will always take this way now! (: thanks

Comment: 9 kegs later only doing this way. My kegs was never so good before, this method is awesome. Fast enough and accurate!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would have to change anything.

As 30 PSI is the same in a any sized container.

Comment: Yes, 30 psi is 30 psi in any sized container, but do you ever inflate an road bike tire and a mountain bike tire with the same pressure? It takes more time and amount of air to fill the mtb larger tire. So my question was because I don't have a way to measure the carbonation properly doing this 'fast way' carbonating. But now I realized that I don't want 30 psi in my beer, I just want to carbonate it fast (don't need to be 10 minutes, just less than a day) and properly. It seems like this method above works! (set it and shake it) But thanks anyway for your answer, it helps me to think about!